# Java console flickering and bugging out in Eclipse

Tags: java, console

So when I run this code:[my code to make a short game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VaWB.png)
My console just starts doing weird things and the only way I can close my console is by clicking on "terminate".

This is my video showing the actual problem.
https://youtu.be/n613dXt_sr0

Comment: It does what you coded: an infinite loop in which only the if branch is executed. `begincijfer = scan.nextlnt();` is inside the `else` instead of before the `if`. So it does not wait for user input. By the way, please add code as text instead of as an image to Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: The flickering is just because your code is stuck in a tight loop outputing a couple of lines again and again. Eclipse is struggling to keep up with all the output.

Comment: Rather than posting an image of your code, it's more helpful to include the code in your question. This way, folks can easily try it out as well as copy/paste/correct into an answer. Hope this helps! Welcome to StackOverflow!